# Making a bean parameter optional

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the below route and bean to get the message from the property file. In some message I have to replace the arguments in the message. Therefore I have looked for a solution without writing 2 methods in the bean one with arguments (`getMessageWithArgs`) and the second without arguments (`getMessage`).

Is it doable to get rid of `getMessageWithArgs` in the bean by using DSL in the route or to make the arguments in the `getMessage` optional so I have at the end one method in the bean?

**Route**

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("activemq:queue:1234")
        .setHeader("functionId", simple(FUNCTION_ID))
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                Message message = exchange.getIn();
                message.setHeader("messageId", "notice_1234_error_messageBox_1");
//              List<String> arguments = Arrays.asList("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");
//              message.setHeader("arguments", arguments);
            }   
        })
    .setHeader("message").method("messageBean", "getMessage( ${header.functionId}, ${header.messageId})")
    //.setHeader("message").method("messageBean", "getMessageWithArgs( ${header.functionId}, ${header.messageId}, ${header.arguments})") 
    .log("after calling getMessageWithoutValidation: ${body}");
}
```

---

**Bean**

```
@Component
public class MessageBean {

    public String getMessage(@Header("functionId") String functionId, 
            @Header("messageId") String messageId) {
        //Doing something to get the message
        return message;
    }


    public String getMessageWithArgs(@Header("functionId") String functionId,
            @Header("messageId") String messageId, 
            @Header("arguments") List<String>  arguments) {
        //Doing something to get the message
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's done all the time with two methods, one calling the other with the default-Parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to keep only one method, keep only the method where you have all arguments knowing that if the header `arguments` has not been set, its value will be `null`.

```
public String getMessage(@Header("functionId") String functionId,
        @Header("messageId") String messageId, 
        @Header("arguments") List<String>  arguments) {
    if (arguments == null || arguments.isEmpty()) {
       // No arguments have been provided
    } else {
       // Arguments have been provided
    }
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Arbitrary Number of Arguments may work for you.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs

So the Bean now will be only one like:

```
public String getMessageWithArgs(@Header("functionId") String functionId, 
            @Header("arguments") String... arguments) {
        String messageId = arguments[0];
        //Doing something to get the message
        return message;
    }
```

I'm not sure if it can be like that, but it might be a way can help..